# Incremente row (VBA) and then Using SommeProduct (probleme with Sommeproduct Excel)

Tags: vba, excel

Thanks to help me)))

At first I incremente the row + 1 with the value that I have insert with VBA. That's working...

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Données Enregistrées").Range("A10:AL10").Copy _
        Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Données Enregistrées").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

And then I want to use the value that I have insert to modify them..I use excel for that.. and I got 0...But If I insert value by hand that's working...

```
=SOMMEPROD((A16:A22=A2)*(B16:B22))
```

Any Solution??

Hope that you have understood, thanks)))

Comment: That formula won't work with that "=A2" on it, that's why you have the 0 result, i think the formula you wan't it this one:
=SOMMEPROD(A16:A22;B16:B22)

Comment: Dear, Thanks but I have to say that I want the value beside the value of A2... It's working when I insert the value by hand, just not working with formule inside...((((

Comment: you're trying to put that formula on vba? using vba to place the formula on a cell? i can't understand what you wan't exactly

Comment: Is `=SOMMEPROD((A16:A22=A2)*(B16:B22))` an array formula?

Comment: Dear, My objectif is to take value in B, C...D...and I know the value from in the column A (per exemple: A2=5...I want to take the value in the row 5(column A) and column B...intersection...But that doesn't wrk because I ve copy the row with VBA...I think..

Comment: It may help to edit your post to include a "text grid" (a couple of rows and columns) representation of what you're trying to do, or a small screen shot of your spreadsheet.

Comment: @Bissoloti Is it working properly? If it is, please validate the answer with the tick right under the down vote, so that we can close the subject. If it's not we will help you to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sommeprod (sumproduct for english) on entire columns like this :

```
=SOMMEPROD((A:A=D2)*(B:B)*1)
```

But if you test a value that is in the same column it can be a problem I think, so show us a bit more so we can answer more accurately!

And yes, SommeProd is an array formula so you have to do Ctrl+Shift+Enter when you are done typing it!

A bientôt

Comment: Maybe in recents Excels versions, but it's still a good practice to know!